# Custom Help Command removing specific commands like owner or admin commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So i made a discord bot following few tutorials and i made a custom help command so i dont want the help command to display some commands such as load or unload cogs command few owner or admin commands. But i a not exactly able to figure out how to do it i checked a few similar posts but in that the created a cog with owner commands but my commands is spread across a few cogs. I am a bit new to discord.py so please guide me. Thank You!! in advance

So this is my custom help command code:-

```
import random
from typing import Optional
from discord import Embed
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext.menus import MenuPages, ListPageSource
from discord.ext.commands import Cog
from discord.ext.commands import command

colors = [0xFFE4E1, 0x00FF7F, 0xD8BFD8, 0xDC143C, 0xFF4500, 0xDEB887, 0xADFF2F, 0x800000, 0x4682B4, 0x006400, 0x808080, 0xA0522D, 0xF08080, 0xC71585, 0xFFB6C1, 0x00CED1]

def syntax(command):
    cmd_and_aliases = "|".join([str(command), *command.aliases])
    params = []

    for key, value in command.params.items():
        if key not in ("self", "ctx"):
            params.append(f"[{key}]" if "NoneType" in str(value) else f"<{key}>")

    params = " ".join(params)

    return f"`{cmd_and_aliases} {params}`"


class HelpMenu(ListPageSource):
    def __init__(self, ctx, data):
        self.ctx = ctx

        super().__init__(data, per_page=5)

    async def write_page(self, menu, fields=[]):
        offset = (menu.current_page*self.per_page) + 1
        len_data = len(self.entries)

        embed = Embed(title="Help",
                      description="Welcome to the help dialog!",
                      colour= random.choice(colors))
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.ctx.guild.me.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{offset:,} - {min(len_data, offset+self.per_page-1):,} of {len_data:,} commands.")

        for name, value in fields:
            embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=False)

        return embed

    async def format_page(self, menu, entries):
        fields = []

        for entry in entries:
            fields.append((entry.brief or "No description", f"-{syntax(entry)}"))

        return await self.write_page(menu, fields)


class Help(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.bot.remove_command("help")

    async def cmd_help(self, ctx, command):
        embed = Embed(title=f"Help with `{command}`",
                      description=f"-{syntax(command)}",
                      colour=random.choice(colors))
        embed.add_field(name="Command description", value=command.help)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


    @command(name="help", brief="Help", help="Gives the info of the commands.")
    async def show_help(self, ctx, cmd: Optional[str]):
        """Shows this message."""
        if cmd is None:
            x = list(self.bot.commands)
            menu = MenuPages(source=HelpMenu(ctx, x))
            await menu.start(ctx)

        else:
            if (command := get(self.bot.commands, name=cmd)):
                await self.cmd_help(ctx, command)

            else:
                await ctx.send("That command does not exist.")

    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("help ready")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Help(bot))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [`hidden`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.hidden) keyword argument in `@command` and not display commands that have `hidden=True` in your help command :)
Also, you should probably subclass [`commands.HelpCommand`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.HelpCommand) instead. [Here's a good tutorial on how to.](https://gist.github.com/InterStella0/b78488fb28cadf279dfd3164b9f0cf96)

Comment: but hidden keyword is for default help command and not custom i already tried hidden kwarg plus my custom help command is iterating list over discord.ext.command.core objects so all commands are getting listed.

Comment: I know that, but that doesn't stop you from accessing the attribute and implementing your own ignore functionality. When you do `x = list(self.bot.commands)` you can remove the commands from `x` which are hidden (you can use list concatenation here: `x = [c for c in self.bot.commands if not c.hidden]`) and check the attribute in the `if (command := ...` statement

Comment: ok thank you its kinda late here so i will check it tommorow. Also if you could could you please include the check for hidden command in your answer if their are people viewing it in future plus for me it will be easier for them. Thanks a lot!!! tho